# Lowering Zune volume and playing audio file?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

At the moment in my app I pause any music the phone is playing and use a MediaElement to play any sounds. After the sound plays the music continues. Everything works fine but now I would like to lower the music volume rather than stop it.

1) Can this be done on wp7?

2) If so how? as I tried changing the volume like so.

```
void PauseMusic()
{
   FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
   // Pause the Zune player if it is already playing music.
   if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
   {
      //MediaPlayer.Pause();
      MediaPlayer.Volume = 0.7f;
      resumeMediaPlayerAfterDone = true;
   }
 }
```

Audio is played like so.

```
void PlayAudioCue(string path)
{
    PauseMusic();
    AudioPlayer.Stop();            
    AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri("/Audio/" + path, UriKind.Relative);            
}

void AudioPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AudioPlayer.Position = new TimeSpan(0);
    AudioPlayer.Volume = 1;
    AudioPlayer.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I bet you want to publish your app to the marketplace. **It will fail the certification process**. Look at 6.5.1 paragraph – Initial Launch Functionality

> When the user is already playing music on the phone when the application is launched, the application must not pause, resume, or
>   stop the active music in the phone MediaQueue by calling the
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer class.
>
> If the application plays its own background music or adjusts
>   background music volume, it must ask the user for consent to stop
>   playing/adjust the background music (e.g. message dialog or settings
>   menu). This prompt must occur each time the application launches,
>   unless there is an opt-in setting provided to the user and the user
>   has used this setting to opt-in.

[More details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184838%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

I'm not 100% sure, but you cannot lower the volume of user's music.

Comment: Way ahead of ya as I already ask the user's permission to stop the music :-)